# The data type of the table I included in my project with ADO.NET is different

Tags: c#, ado.net

There is a column named "value" from the table in the database and the data type of this column is "sql_variant".

Here is my MeteringPointProperties class created by ado.net:

```
public partial class MeteringPointProperties
{
    [Key]
    [Column(Order = 0)]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
    public int MeteringPointID { get; set; }

    [Key]
    [Column(Order = 1)]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
    public int ID { get; set; }

    public virtual MeteringPoints MeteringPoints { get; set; }
}
```

When I want to access the value somewhere, I'm accessing the properties of the "MeteringPoints" table. But the only relationship between these 2 tables is my first column holding the meteringpointsId, so it has nothing to do with the "value" column.

I never changed the type of this property. Because I don't know how it will behave on the database side.